# paper-input - float label on clicking the input field

Tags: material-design, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

paper-input floats its label only when the user types in the first character. Is it possible to float the label as soon as the user clicks on it? For example, refer https://unacademy.in/ login screen input fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`always-float-label`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-alwaysFloatLabel), [`no-label-float`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-noLabelFloat) properties/attributes of `paper-input` In an `on-click` event to achieve this. `paper-input` [demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-input) shows how to use `always-float-label`, `no-label-float` properties/attributes.

A demo could be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Label float</title>

    <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
    

</head>

<body>

<my-form></my-form>  
  <dom-module id="my-form">  
   <template> 
  
     <paper-input name="name" id="name" label="name" on-click="_click" on-blur="_blur"></paper-input>
  
    </template> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Polymer({
        is:"my-form",
        _click:function (){
          //console.log(this.$.name.value);
          this.$.name.alwaysFloatLabel=true;
        },
        _blur:function(){
         this.$.name.alwaysFloatLabel=false;
       }
      })
    
    </script>
</dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I already know always-float-label and no-label-float properties. I wanted the label to float on click event, and to restore when I click outside.

Comment: You haven't mentioned it in your question, that you know about it, Anyway I have updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

A 'better' way:

```
<paper-input label="Name" focused="{{focused}}" always-float-label="[[focused]]"></paper-input>
```

To explain, this is a pure data binding solution. `focused` sets a read only boolean and `always-float-label` takes a boolean. Simply bind the values so `always-float-label` is in sync with `focused` (where `always-float-label` only reads the value set using `[[` `]]`).